# Can I replace Ubuntu With Fedora without loosing my data?

Tags: ubuntu, fedora

I want to replace Ubuntu with fedora but I dont know if I can keep all my data. If possible, I would like to also keep my installed apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Practically, you are going to need to reinstall programs when switching between distributions, especially ones as different as Ubuntu and Fedora.  That's because they have totally different packaging systems and install software in different ways, and the binaries from one are generally not going to run on the other, due to differing shared library versions.

If your `/home` directory is on a separate partition, then yes, you can preserve it when reinstalling and keep your data.  Otherwise, your best bet is to back up your home directory and then reinstall and restore.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question!